# split rows based on a column listing numerical values in R

Tags: r, split, row

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Name<-c("v","v","x","y","z")
Position<-c(2,"5;7",3,198,"3;4")
Score<-c(0,100,200,144,3)
df<-data.frame(Name, Position, Score)
df
      Name Position Score
1    v        2     0
2    v      5;7   100
3    x        3   200
4    y      198   144
5    z      3,4     3
```

In the column `df$Position`, occasionally I have two (or more) numbers (for example in rows 2 and 5). I would like to duplicate these rows so each of them contains just one of these values. So the output looks like this:

```
      Name Position Score
1     v         2      0
2     v         5    100
3     v         7    100
4     x         3    200
5     y       198    144
6     z         3      3
7     z         4      3
```

I would also want `df$Position` to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(Position, convert = TRUE)
#   Name Position Score
#1    v        2     0
#2    v        5   100
#3    v        7   100
#4    x        3   200
#5    y      198   144
#6    z        3     3
#7    z        4     3
```

Comment: @Wera If it is a factor column, try tor change it to character class i.e. `df %>% mutate(Position = as.character(Position)) %>% separate_rows(Position, convert = TRUE)`